# How to manually change processor ID?

Tags: spoofing, mask

Looking for a way to manually spoof my Processor ID.

I found that it's located in DMIEDIT although I'm unable to edit it directly through DMIEDIT.
On DMIEDIT it says it's a DWORD data type although I am unable to locate the file in Regedit.

Unless there's another program/software that would allow me to edit this.

I've embedded the image of my ProcessorID number which I'm trying to change.
[image: ProcessorID]

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know this is impossible.

From Microsoft's
[Win32_Processor class](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/cimwin32prov/win32-processor?redirectedfrom=MSDN):

> ProcessorId
>
> Data type: string
> Access type: **Read-only**

Comment: There are programs such as spoofers that have the ability to do this.

I read somewhere that you could spoof CPU serials by "creating a new smbios table where you put spoofed information and then set the smbios physical address stored in the .data section in ntoskrnl to the physical address of the newly created table." Although I'm not sure how I would go about doing this.

Comment: Perhaps such a program exists, but Windows itself cannot do this.